Inverse of scalar multiplication in elliptic curve
I know a point $Q$ on an elliptic curve $E$. Also, I know $k$ which is $kP = Q$ for some $P$. If the order of $E$ is coprime, we can simply compute inverse of $k$ to find out $P$. But how can I compute $P$ if $k$ is not coprime with the order of $E$?
I think there should be multiple possibilities with $P$, and I want to find out all of them.

@JoséCarlosSantos: This is one of those rare questions that reads perfectly well without MathJax!
